# will you be able to drag unwanted files unto the trash on the unity Launcher?

Tags: unity, 11.04, launcher, trash

When unity for Natty is finished, will there be a feature to drag and drop unwanted files into the trash that is docked on the launcher?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Here's [the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/619686) to track.